# Conditional probabilities prove false

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I need to show by example that the following formula is not always true:

$P(A ∣ B ∪ C) = P(A ∣ B) + P(A ∣ C), B ∩ C = NULL $

Comment: Just try it with explicit events.  Consider a roll of a fair die for instance, and come up with a few events to try.

Comment: Just look at it for a specific case.  Say, given the toss of a die, that $A$ is the event "an even number is tossed".  Then let $B$ be the event "$1$ is tossed" and $C$ the event "$2$ is tossed.".  Now, what are $P(A|B),P(A|C)$ and $P(A|B\cup C)$?

Comment: I think you need to look up conditional probability.  Given that $B$ occurred, $A$ is clearly not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be one blue card and two red cards. The blue card has a black dot on it. One red card has a black dot and the other a white dot on it.
Pick a card at random. Define

$A$ - 'The card is red'
$B$ - 'The card has a white dot on it'
$C$ - 'The card has a black dot on it'

Compute $P(A) = 2/3$, $P(B) = 1/3$, $P(C) = 2/3$. Also $P(A\cap B) = 1/3 $ and $P(A\cap C) = 1/3$. Then
$$P(A|B\cup C) = 2/3,\qquad P(A|B) = 1,\qquad P(A|C) = 1/2 $$
so the RHS wouldn't even be a probability.

Comment: how can the sum of the three probabilities P(A), P(B), P(C) go over 1?

Comment: @OscarTheMighty because the events $A,B,C$ are not pairwise disjoint